# Exceptions bringing down cassandra 3.3 cluster

Tags: cassandra

This is a rather large post of seemingly related issues and we've posted to the Cassandra user list as well. We're using Cassandra 3.3 and our development been trying to track down some new issues we’ve been seeing on one of our pre-prod environments where we’ve been having consistent failures very often (every day or every 2-3 days), even if load/number of transactions are very light.
We’re running a 2 data center deployment with 3 nodes in each data center. Our tables are setup with replication factor = 2 and we have 16G dedicated to the heap with the G1GC for garbage collection. Our systems are AWS M4.2xlarge with 8 CPUs and 32GB of RAM and we have 2 general purpose EBS volumes on each node of 500GB each.
Once we hit this it seems like the only way to recover is to shutdown the cluster and restart. Running repairs after the restart often results in failures and we pretty much end up having to truncate the tables before starting up clean again. We are not sure if the two are inter-related. We pretty much see the same issue on all the nodes.

If anyone has any tips or any suggestions on how to diagnose/debug this further, it will help a great deal! The issues are:

Issue 1: Once the errors occur they just repeat for a bit followed by the errors in issue 2.

```
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:165] 2017-01-08 08:32:39,915 AutoSavingCache.java:386 - Saved KeyCache (63 items) in 5 ms
INFO  [IndexSummaryManager:1] 2017-01-08 08:32:41,438 IndexSummaryRedistribution.java:74 - Redistributing index summaries
INFO  [HANDSHAKE-ahldataslave4.bos.manhattan.aspect-cloud.net/10.184.8.224] 2017-01-08 09:30:03,988 OutboundTcpConnection.java:505 - Handshaking version with ahldataslave4.bos.manhattan.aspect-cloud.net/10.184.8.224
INFO  [IndexSummaryManager:1] 2017-01-08 09:32:41,440 IndexSummaryRedistribution.java:74 - Redistributing index summaries
WARN  [SharedPool-Worker-9] 2017-01-08 10:30:00,116 BatchStatement.java:289 - Batch of prepared statements for [manhattan.rcmessages] is of size 9264, exceeding specified threshold of 5120 by 4144.
INFO  [IndexSummaryManager:1] 2017-01-08 10:32:41,442 IndexSummaryRedistribution.java:74 - Redistributing index summaries
INFO  [IndexSummaryManager:1] 2017-01-08 11:32:41,443 IndexSummaryRedistribution.java:74 - Redistributing index summaries
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:162] 2017-01-08 12:32:39,914 AutoSavingCache.java:386 - Saved KeyCache (108 items) in 4 ms
INFO  [IndexSummaryManager:1] 2017-01-08 12:32:41,446 IndexSummaryRedistribution.java:74 - Redistributing index summaries
INFO  [IndexSummaryManager:1] 2017-01-08 13:32:41,448 IndexSummaryRedistribution.java:74 - Redistributing index summaries
INFO  [IndexSummaryManager:1] 2017-01-08 14:32:41,450 IndexSummaryRedistribution.java:74 - Redistributing index summaries
INFO  [IndexSummaryManager:1] 2017-01-08 15:32:41,451 IndexSummaryRedistribution.java:74 - Redistributing index summaries
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:170] 2017-01-08 16:32:39,915 AutoSavingCache.java:386 - Saved KeyCache (109 items) in 4 ms
INFO  [IndexSummaryManager:1] 2017-01-08 16:32:41,453 IndexSummaryRedistribution.java:74 - Redistributing index summaries
WARN  [SharedPool-Worker-4] 2017-01-08 17:30:45,048 AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:169 - Uncaught exception on thread Thread[SharedPool-Worker-4,5,main]: {}
java.lang.AssertionError: null
at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.BufferCell.<init>(BufferCell.java:49) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.BufferCell.tombstone(BufferCell.java:88) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.BufferCell.tombstone(BufferCell.java:83) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.BufferCell.purge(BufferCell.java:175) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.ComplexColumnData.lambda$purge$107(ComplexColumnData.java:165) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at org.apache.cassandra.utils.btree.BTree$FiltrationTracker.apply(BTree.java:650) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at org.apache.cassandra.utils.btree.BTree.transformAndFilter(BTree.java:693) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at org.apache.cassandra.utils.btree.BTree.transformAndFilter(BTree.java:668) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.ComplexColumnData.transformAndFilter(ComplexColumnData.java:170) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.ComplexColumnData.purge(ComplexColumnData.java:165) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.ComplexColumnData.purge(ComplexColumnData.java:43) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.BTreeRow.lambda$purge$102(BTreeRow.java:333) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at org.apache.cassandra.utils.btree.BTree$FiltrationTracker.apply(BTree.java:650) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at org.apache.cassandra.utils.btree.BTree.transformAndFilter(BTree.java:693) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at org.apache.cassandra.utils.btree.BTree.transformAndFilter(BTree.java:668) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.BTreeRow.transformAndFilter(BTreeRow.java:338) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.BTreeRow.purge(BTreeRow.java:333) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.partitions.PurgeFunction.applyToRow(PurgeFunction.java:88) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.transform.BaseRows.hasNext(BaseRows.java:116) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.UnfilteredRowIteratorSerializer.serialize(UnfilteredRowIteratorSerializer.java:133) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.UnfilteredRowIteratorSerializer.serialize(UnfilteredRowIteratorSerializer.java:89) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.UnfilteredRowIteratorSerializer.serialize(UnfilteredRowIteratorSerializer.java:79) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.partitions.UnfilteredPartitionIterators$Serializer.serialize(UnfilteredPartitionIterators.java:294) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.ReadResponse$LocalDataResponse.build(ReadResponse.java:134) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.ReadResponse$LocalDataResponse.<init>(ReadResponse.java:127) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.ReadResponse$LocalDataResponse.<init>(ReadResponse.java:123) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.ReadResponse.createDataResponse(ReadResponse.java:65) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.ReadCommand.createResponse(ReadCommand.java:292) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.ReadCommandVerbHandler.doVerb(ReadCommandVerbHandler.java:50) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessageDeliveryTask.run(MessageDeliveryTask.java:64) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService$FutureTask.run(AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:164) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService$LocalSessionFutureTask.run(AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:136) [apache-cassandra-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.SEPWorker.run(SEPWorker.java:105) [apache-cassandra-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
```

Issue 2:

```
WARN  [SharedPool-Worker-2] 2017-01-09 05:18:58,880 AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:169 - Uncaught exception on thread Thread[SharedPool-Worker-2,5,main]: {}
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy$DroppableRunnable.run(StorageProxy.java:2461) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService$FutureTask.run(AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:164) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService$LocalSessionFutureTask.run(AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:136) [apache-cassandra-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.SEPWorker.run(SEPWorker.java:105) [apache-cassandra-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
WARN  [SharedPool-Worker-1] 2017-01-09 05:19:14,220 AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:169 - Uncaught exception on thread Thread[SharedPool-Worker-1,5,main]: {}
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy$DroppableRunnable.run(StorageProxy.java:2461) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService$FutureTask.run(AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:164) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService$LocalSessionFutureTask.run(AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:136) [apache-cassandra-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.SEPWorker.run(SEPWorker.java:105) [apache-cassandra-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
WARN  [SharedPool-Worker-1] 2017-01-09 05:19:29,876 AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:169 - Uncaught exception on thread Thread[SharedPool-Worker-1,5,main]: {}
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
WARN  [SharedPool-Worker-1] 2017-01-09 05:19:45,217 AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:169 - Uncaught exception on thread Thread[SharedPool-Worker-1,5,main]: {}
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
WARN  [SharedPool-Worker-2] 2017-01-09 05:20:00,241 AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:169 - Uncaught exception on thread Thread[SharedPool-Worker-2,5,main]: {}
```

Issue 3: Periodic warnings about leaks (this was during a repair) - we had an OOM occurrence about a week ago:

```
INFO  [Thread-9] 2017-01-09 15:01:11,828 RepairSession.java:237 - [repair #7593ad41-d67c-11e6-a76f-f1d6fd321f0d] new session: will sync ahldataslave1.bos.manhattan.aspect-cloud.net/10.184.8.151, /10.184.8.137, /10.184.8.219, /10.184.8.224 on range [(4815877001221178276,4825317823493984218], (3375739423664266689,3378070249246945856], (-7393599445401300009,-7393031105803218575], (-8130357422229977058,-8127934975152946543], (-4611683212167667055,-4597307445147354114], (4829191785668845783,4847928037092763493], (5522544388079333104,5528633388915935404], (1021118078158195547,1032730403399741255], (-20739833830226207,-14719054523073734], (-6205449048248449637,-6203730539323274527], (45435932670861622,69554714149031706], (148647262653106287,181904829526383862], (-854190757691833472,-854087983203765538], (-7714687510919982336,-7700463340346726648], (-360739232930366185,-339249720009847821], (524595904743716879,537371267474489752], (8185882494697143291,8187345181917158585], (181904829526383862,190096166859570216], (-1152328644109499972,-1134711681717758961], (-586016578220869954,-566687033455187734], (-4597307445147354114,-4541034774723552824], (-4488655272471923458,-4481233629800439836], (3111053603069111732,3121096557789915147], (-1167831376731724655,-1152328644109499972], (-6302582962631272172,-6290099341099600242], (8082429902489189721,8084233962135014968], (-2781993705200227829,-2777492754784519178], (5996816756578981045,6022011570976925279], (4404919629779433734,4422232637329318322], (-643317786131863042,-611582394998065454], (4514099138058135901,4514906323961126580], (7273471227296986256,7316794306200362675], (4462984376163219141,4464984714163480487], (-2390509810947844616,-2382282465250439153], (-7773729052257068390,-7772926086336061342], (-161569209320145017,-149914302996366392], (1392011488470148469,1403436343776848669], (546940383302067460,574197777751440495], (6624568645457217871,6629411218351717560], (-1134711681717758961,-1133755953039077472], (-7248281701751445296,-7243217407431962906], (2374653705052569734,2377396978942737768], (5619550734131192401,5628464353424177974], (-192925818286153751,-181902834109073167], (5896301416900157412,5911734690958039138], (4422232637329318322,4462984376163219141], (-4524564105581793254,-4504900851715014673], (-2115528876758613050,-2112322288682500569], (5504098260114685179,5515264579319185925], (35614519826275404,45435932670861622], (-855913784497695841,-854190757691833472], (5736245318761313405,5738445441111493493], (4807463771329802801,4815877001221178276], (-2884278504117308670,-2881329894351532736], (-207545241327995479,-207389332352346254], (-181902834109073167,-172819893538312319], (-7636862515759014032,-7626686102011136779], (-8140870857704067579,-8130357422229977058], (-2342122616740401439,-2335433185444036860], (-2881329894351532736,-2880349360092682175], (-611582394998065454,-587918354120388686], (-7320730625612121443,-7317644215584737598], (-13045270760172222,8260384715982984], (-8668935926714005039,-8657580917928283146], (8260384715982984,35614519826275404], (2861067483327829799,2864748323206840859], (3127114336475141934,3139163273099443478], (-7657420721193956821,-7636862515759014032], (1032730403399741255,1032951438204062821], (-1133755953039077472,-1130095656542041882], (5515264579319185925,5522544388079333104], (6826479291574328528,6828593995008227175], (658600138550738740,680809612853177633], (2364271158745468459,2374653705052569734], (2864748323206840859,2868871349367827459], (-7741910906325473118,-7738712583959975589], (2749562470526527976,2765502980561577063], (4569656624441412194,4581277061087905130], (-1130095656542041882,-1102822102812415509], (2357686856375407577,2364271158745468459], (2875146491882456097,2913694653712675567], (-2365721528619247416,-2362417204623405805], (-7700463340346726648,-7657420721193956821], (-1545400958003324469,-1527145992709891047], (6595468060656389384,6611122695943865425], (-2362417204623405805,-2360989147149959339], (680809612853177633,691564499046700936], (1048818468740031469,1051848236340749987], (-6290099341099600242,-6284139189426371408], (-430511209136180745,-417631748808875679], (-2127191227331961211,-2115528876758613050], (-587918354120388686,-586016578220869954], (5950659959556897324,5972536818860340742], (7228681112293176899,7273471227296986256], (-92115275177849392,-73078256610822906], (-2150182737057335813,-2131084968707606517], (-5931891237188071234,-5925084712702354100], (1854063092500381970,1894128417137542926], (3139163273099443478,3144353879892041737], (2795130016444690338,2849989872521310320], (69554714149031706,73259277905023853], (-198884270246085916,-192925818286153751], (2301867852127537258,2344138511230415627], (-2360989147149959339,-2342122616740401439], (2868871349367827459,2875146491882456097], (-8520120040026037727,-8484758828657908805], (1044175704807438060,1048818468740031469], (3658700192210846721,3709106004630729567], (-8715352510373593584,-8695484052773103051], (4825317823493984218,4829191785668845783], (5881177751245354064,5896301416900157412], (-1557733846751863547,-1545400958003324469], (3764340229927726801,3772352737530248438], (5723087139361841478,5736245318761313405], (-339249720009847821,-325063001525001753], (4581277061087905130,4585591969590606261], (2849989872521310320,2861067483327829799], (-201641945389990466,-198884270246085916], (3062119490734517386,3070339219117072282], (6611989977644669113,6624568645457217871], (-6303561532875621980,-6302582962631272172], (-2880349360092682175,-2815907193866317595], (-2210673969380244356,-2200655423201071981], (6920406973111913689,6944396390330370813], (3070339219117072282,3089918739923672617], (1018479337556218583,1021118078158195547], (-22373917471115570,-20802161777184740], (2349224556257120691,2357686856375407577], (1610291395978708348,1610350862682840167], (-7774308296105089774,-7773729052257068390], (-207389332352346254,-201641945389990466], (-4504900851715014673,-4488655272471923458], (-913362829471550684,-900550299179500948], (574197777751440495,575687259162456966], (-209852186312631406,-207545241327995479], (3961560378473489131,4029122901768525705], (1059898575782522398,1065913666232086022], (6611122695943865425,6611989977644669113], (-2815907193866317595,-2781993705200227829], (-8149621014270042242,-8140870857704067579], (-999997390934570392,-998678768267637866], (2377396978942737768,2384267095612056863], (-2267001694418802171,-2210871230482048364], (-2131084968707606517,-2127191227331961211], (3144353879892041737,3183343610940682057], (-2210871230482048364,-2210673969380244356], (4399306102077085676,4404919629779433734], (537371267474489752,546940383302067460], (-7722143244670988745,-7714687510919982336], (3754196018068729018,3763367677110000435], (-5925084712702354100,-5919412889821651249], (4585591969590606261,4590124192625756967], (-1189315862160445133,-1167831376731724655], (-14719054523073734,-13045270760172222], (3772352737530248438,3791853264732937441], (-149914302996366392,-138596249554837825], (-1459586834232833970,-1455782887662096513], (-7626686102011136779,-7613607518487725198], (-2370342707880863831,-2365721528619247416], (1051848236340749987,1059898575782522398], (575687259162456966,587747968172054843], (1846675642540253784,1854063092500381970], (5911734690958039138,5950659959556897324], (3709106004630729567,3754196018068729018], (2274687735800823626,2301867852127537258], (3763367677110000435,3764340229927726801], (2765502980561577063,2768302382460911776], (-4835698441475193016,-4821740368643417588], (-4840592682190099042,-4835698441475193016], (-900550299179500948,-898509802837897450], (5972536818860340742,5996816756578981045], (7316794306200362675,7316948326538779302], (-20802161777184740,-20739833830226207], (-8695484052773103051,-8693825425156218047], (-6228811049824135380,-6205449048248449637], (-8522744988679262888,-8520120040026037727], (-1527145992709891047,-1522580222898594256], (1065913666232086022,1070185844169898505], (3121096557789915147,3127114336475141934]] for manhattan.[config, messages, rcmessages, csseedmessages, metadata, rqmessages]
ERROR [Reference-Reaper:1] 2017-01-09 15:01:12,481 Ref.java:202 - LEAK DETECTED: a reference (org.apache.cassandra.utils.concurrent.Ref$State@8520181) to class org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader$InstanceTidier@110489339:/data/manhattan/messages-5e11ec20d49411e6ac36cb64da3c5bcf/ma-1-big was not released before the reference was garbage collected
ERROR [Reference-Reaper:1] 2017-01-09 15:01:12,481 Ref.java:202 - LEAK DETECTED: a reference (org.apache.cassandra.utils.concurrent.Ref$State@2aa6af1) to class org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader$InstanceTidier@1202250944:/data/manhattan/rcmessages-5f65e360d49411e6ac36cb64da3c5bcf/ma-1-big was not released before the reference was garbage collected
ERROR [Reference-Reaper:1] 2017-01-09 15:01:12,481 Ref.java:202 - LEAK DETECTED: a reference (org.apache.cassandra.utils.concurrent.Ref$State@5feebbbd) to class org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader$InstanceTidier@1990550669:/data/manhattan/rcmessages-5f65e360d49411e6ac36cb64da3c5bcf/ma-2-big was not released before the reference was garbage collected
```

Issue 4: Failure on repair (cannot complete repair) - validation failures.

```
INFO  [Thread-9] 2017-01-09 15:01:12,496 RepairSession.java:237 - [repair #75f99b00-d67c-11e6-a76f-f1d6fd321f0d] new session: will sync ahldataslave1.bos.manhattan.aspect-cloud.net/10.184.8.151, /10.184.8.136, /10.184.8.219, /10.184.8.206 on range [(7070473513877450523,7071785512108503562], (7540323476844137856,7551069853951512536], (6496851087781126402,6506947825241172690], (4956723654110177663,4997988272614120716], (6159728418399742238,6161785046042182181], (-6111201816165886930,-6109358652076682027], (6765434292326999735,6786216263996459971], (5670991529662923445,5678922736379606122], (-8368452819419163190,-8352559832808839636], (-3579114434972148656,-3552744642655983590], (7574005965138357735,7575976736757457093], (3443342880213529041,3448513378658973391], (-6374441519731158925,-6368083975098827965], (1506273267531550913,1508155162580364084], (-3841814855559153943,-3835938678769454001], (9170965416227969215,9181174655986386320], (-6589650497263617394,-6578994961053045565], (-7526495575912144496,-7518448902193774650], (3448513378658973391,3466857105667177973], (7553098986919382391,7574005965138357735], (-7927877550785715833,-7927648953253692861], (8525761079018902513,8533541215797136240], (-9020129600263662082,-9010501329825003246], (1090724998362773160,1097939939665235297], (6495099300248039972,6496851087781126402], (6161785046042182181,6230901034893815059], (-7463338857564269606,-7459175745770455573], (-5365113529531278290,-5358403398116793300], (2249898065901245108,2256752991177466019], (427458615961451939,456792456721828910], (-7518448902193774650,-7476577165771266744], (8496964666711176665,8503454084084785332], (1508155162580364084,1531943799366406071], (1623939448991457330,1628591069075100791], (2500969373198505595,2510256322219581447], (1487072216030226303,1506273267531550913], (-8842784826526224555,-8840216173643212475], (2233348668129647030,2247658708769712814], (-8289206614243730701,-8287074180401539509], (-7476577165771266744,-7470389682785988771], (3509709684061378867,3512938839959595162], (1296769759309759534,1302830049359124705], (7575976736757457093,7612135532866611803], (7539950122318008545,7540323476844137856], (-1860975172751451123,-1853676643512030698], (-8116786947316919605,-8107369675963369796], (-5576866678991811211,-5548824138592035245], (-9211881728677655622,-9209566963086044390], (7489367377277174970,7511259639253940249], (1302830049359124705,1310010318365119318], (-8750733220711433842,-8741408722769214425], (-6060376367842620341,-6049131555099770258], (2476529278549364684,2476659930520260878], (-4418742343319617797,-4384333951548488071], (1930660747072472501,1946687557062422024], (-3702380150896445622,-3691910222307497728], (-4419703203609450987,-4418742343319617797], (7551697213870628887,7553098986919382391], (-7909869864636951454,-7904683595914140744], (2492882420790179151,2500969373198505595], (759685512451005610,773693246847159219], (722689136592207691,730821328907957274], (5219025897237634110,5229566135848567231], (4149517035748854868,4162833917677490963], (1326132699179277905,1349642653396670633], (-3552744642655983590,-3549073980410969181], (-4456698363145934960,-4419703203609450987], (-5482989026069906323,-5481213659503324794], (279535406932511121,297415597645494493], (-9204266745720873498,-9161795161892156657], (6786216263996459971,6786883290959946615], (1635462812102810232,1638975594001298412], (1531943799366406071,1546279755200334429], (-3851094911406737954,-3841814855559153943], (8488130353439482734,8496964666711176665], (9146936609495586767,9148689706364420814], (-3674452659583777301,-3669778494255064100], (1546279755200334429,1554992050513055527], (2969501640373218313,2975603144417796179], (-3865994019611705472,-3851094911406737954], (1119818899797211952,1121114266048498658], (5555981883036126656,5559877922798642583], (-9161795161892156657,-9148239227447645822], (-1988480938545038453,-1972594091279542463], (-8457443005098123276,-8426466451426413266], (7527886006442742638,7539950122318008545], (1482724986864293552,1487072216030226303], (218814708185728764,222373457441562248], (-1844742172330357357,-1834186452017037646], (-7914786200548736052,-7909869864636951454], (1554992050513055527,1556471756149638584], (2247658708769712814,2249241162600622119], (2249241162600622119,2249898065901245108], (-6368083975098827965,-6357129727004451888], (1349642653396670633,1372390693080139703], (-5628093303198956105,-5602276528881256607], (-5602276528881256607,-5576866678991811211], (-1972594091279542463,-1932380490869749103], (6746187069375198686,6759453964579921534], (-9209566963086044390,-9204266745720873498], (2969169700471726709,2969501640373218313], (-1846725725884736711,-1844742172330357357], (8466845312658849111,8478632986527402947], (6786883290959946615,6786909234664957611], (-8105207391882034800,-8058995460560987960], (-5481213659503324794,-5480151738028046165], (6152943806705127166,6159728418399742238], (-7931416471770778308,-7927877550785715833], (-7444305315017293180,-7438698090368547807], (-5405765462772655927,-5365113529531278290], (7468218535666030613,7489367377277174970], (7370990959551251700,7384554095789173771], (9181174655986386320,9197356813903415489], (-7891619558235712999,-7886926665775314135], (4863660993721847898,4876110806493712229], (5546813895398001993,5555981883036126656], (6793672076817085638,6817463007248949484], (730821328907957274,741073317079317196], (1285297621466628116,1296769759309759534], (-6109358652076682027,-6097749005908966679], (-3160359268440132710,-3150255443388600113], (-6067028212437311851,-6060376367842620341], (3512938839959595162,3531669213417260709], (-1641724835017736571,-1630212592242213627], (-5631109618795517413,-5628093303198956105], (6759453964579921534,6765434292326999735], (8027648385044762960,8030142266857918084], (1264145341476479882,1285297621466628116], (1116504555019555851,1119818899797211952], (-3139664283152392978,-3138393885745606369], (-1652241560457928053,-1641724835017736571], (8503454084084785332,8525761079018902513], (-1853676643512030698,-1846725725884736711], (1628591069075100791,1635462812102810232], (-8840216173643212475,-8817712049837887184], (-6357129727004451888,-6355060010614218705], (-6097749005908966679,-6088616433680186631], (-7904683595914140744,-7891619558235712999], (-4952793941753266051,-4937049631932742604], (-3150255443388600113,-3139664283152392978], (2512801900471921714,2516325796899709313], (2510256322219581447,2512801900471921714], (-5638226176228799616,-5631109618795517413], (-7886926665775314135,-7882937045572193145], (6786909234664957611,6793672076817085638], (-3691910222307497728,-3674452659583777301], (-4867940821711541762,-4866946150328928181], (7071785512108503562,7081793743588959944], (4876110806493712229,4879643371134562502], (6138845154266790671,6152943806705127166], (-6355060010614218705,-6332373169802347251], (-6125214696594291714,-6111201816165886930], (-7470389682785988771,-7463338857564269606], (-3598204681868075295,-3579114434972148656], (-8107369675963369796,-8105207391882034800], (7612135532866611803,7641727005250566009], (9148689706364420814,9170965416227969215], (6506947825241172690,6515762919020447377], (-6088616433680186631,-6067028212437311851], (741073317079317196,759685512451005610], (-8352559832808839636,-8344010281020219217], (-6049131555099770258,-6043632332003790850], (3494099643169044463,3509709684061378867], (3466857105667177973,3494099643169044463], (7551069853951512536,7551697213870628887], (2476659930520260878,2492882420790179151], (-8842911646480810622,-8842784826526224555], (193808271419729511,198960416318160202], (-4873803694032119901,-4867940821711541762], (-7569775426219162591,-7569610743922997927], (4730391117872973381,4732570096640666262], (9137762516596245936,9146936609495586767], (-9148239227447645822,-9137147760354721369], (-8296203956052422690,-8289206614243730701], (198960416318160202,218814708185728764]] for manhattan.[config, messages, rcmessages, csseedmessages, metadata, rqmessages]
WARN  [SharedPool-Worker-2] 2017-01-09 15:01:38,219 AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:169 - Uncaught exception on thread Thread[SharedPool-Worker-2,5,main]: {}
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy$DroppableRunnable.run(StorageProxy.java:2461) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService$FutureTask.run(AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:164) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService$LocalSessionFutureTask.run(AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:136) [apache-cassandra-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.SEPWorker.run(SEPWorker.java:105) [apache-cassandra-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
WARN  [SharedPool-Worker-2] 2017-01-09 15:04:41,678 AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:169 - Uncaught exception on thread Thread[SharedPool-Worker-2,5,main]: {}
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy$DroppableRunnable.run(StorageProxy.java:2461) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService$FutureTask.run(AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:164) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService$LocalSessionFutureTask.run(AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:136) [apache-cassandra-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.SEPWorker.run(SEPWorker.java:105) [apache-cassandra-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
```

Comment: Did you adjust the cassandra default configuration somehow? Are you using materialized views?

Comment: Nope, not using materialized views in our schema. What do you mean by changing default configuration? We made a few edits to the vm.options file and cassandra.yaml and that's about it.